# Static Comparison of Record Layouts

Tags: ada

I have two records, some fields of which need to be in the same positions within each record. Although this has been heavily commented in the code, it is possible that, in 10 years time, a programmer may change one of the records without changing the other and I would like to create a static check that this has not occurred.

I can create an "active" check in a procedure or function as follows:

```
procedure Main is

    type SimpleRecord1 is record
        FirstItem  : Integer;
        SecondItem : Boolean;
        ThirdItem  : Integer;
        DoNotCare  : Float;
    end record;

    type SimpleRecord2 is record
        Foo        : Integer;
        Bar        : Boolean;
        Baz        : Integer;
        Rfc3092    : Boolean;
    end record;

    MyRecord1 : SimpleRecord1;
    MyRecord2 : SimpleRecord2;
begin
    Pragma Assert ((MyRecord1.FirstItem'Position = MyRecord2.Foo'Position) and
                   (MyRecord1.SecondItem'Position = MyRecord2.Bar'Position) and
                   (MyRecord1.ThirdItem'Position = MyRecord2.Baz'Position));

    Put_Line ("The assert didn't fire");
          
end Main;
```

I am concerned that the first three vairiables have the same offsets within the two records. In the real code there are dozens of other variables within each record which are not the same between the records.

However, I would really like this to be a check, not on instances of the records (MyRecord1, MyRecord2), but on the records themselves (SimpleRecord1, SimpleRecord2). Then it could be placed in the .ads file where the records are defined.

SimpleRecord1.FirstItem'Position

is illegal. Is there a way to create a check without having to make instances and put the code into a function or procedure?

Comment: How would you selectively describe the fields you want to check for similarity of position and the fields you do not want to check for similarity of position using an operator on the record types?

Comment: In the example, both SimpleRecord1 and SimpleRecord2 have been defined. I would want to say that the offset of ThirdItem within an instance of SimpleRecord1 (if I were ever to create one) would be the same as the offset of Baz in an instance of SimpleRecord2 (if I were ever to create one of those). The compiler is aware of how it will allocate an instance of each record, so I feel that the compiler should be able to tell me whether those offsets will always be the same.

Comment: Also consider a _variant record_, examined in the context of [_Handling Variability and Re-usability_](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/Ada_For_The_Embedded_C_Developer/chapters/07_Reusability.html).

Comment: Sounds suspiciously as though you want to convert between the records using some sort of unchecked conversion! Eww. One step on the way might be to use `-gnatR1` (see `gnatmake --help`) to get a report of where the record components are. Or use [rep clauses, ARM 13.5.1(24)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-13-5-1.html#p24) on the records?

Comment: I'm glad to say that the intention is not to do an unchecked conversion between them! The context is in the conversion of a C program which has a structure with next, previous and priority fields as the first three fields for placing (a pointer) to the structure on a linked list. There can be dozens of different types of records/structs that will go onto a linked list of this type, and the software that handles the linked list only cares about those first three fields.  The C programmer uses a static assert using "offsetof" to check that all the structs are suitable for the linked list.

Comment: I don't know how to validate what you want, but what you could do is predefine a record for the header, specifying exact types, sizes, and placement.  Then you create a mixin generic that makes a parent record that forces that header into the right location and places all the additional fields after.  Then you structure your client code to only work with the headers part.  The developers can create a record for the additional fields, instantiate the generic and use the new type created by the generic to map to the C structs.  This forces them to use you header in the correct way.

Comment: When translating a C program to Ada it is beneficial to avoid writing C using Ada. Remember that an Ada access object is not a pointer. Objects of an Ada access type cannot be simply "cast" to another access type. Thus, knowing the location of the access object does not equate to knowing what the object points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the last two comments (by Jere and Jim Rogers) more concrete, indeed the Ada way is to define the types of the list elements so that any kind of element can be placed in the same list, and accessed by the same kind of pointer, without any uncheckable conversions. In the OP's case, IMO the most appropriate method is to make all list elements be tagged records derived from the same abstract parent class where the parent contains the next, prev and priority components. For example like this:

```
type List_Element;
type List_Ptr is access List_Element'Class;
type List_Element is abstract tagged record
   Next, Prev : List_Ptr;
   Priority   : Boolean;
end record;

type Simple_Record_1 is new List_Element with record
   DoNotCare : Float;
end record;

type Simple_Record_2 is new List_Element with record
   Rfc3092 : Boolean;
end record;
```

The SW that handles the linked list deals with List_Ptr values that point to List_Element'Class objects but with only the common components Next, Prev and Priority visible. When there is a need to execute some processing that depends on the actual type of the list element, you can use either a dynamically dispatching call, or a membership test followed by a type conversion, to get from a List_Ptr to the underlying Simple_Record_1, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, using a tagged record introduces the tag field, which will probably make the default layout of the record unusable for interfacing with the C code. The same is true of the discriminant of a variant record. However, with a representation clause one could ensure the tag or discriminant comes after the fields that need to be in fixed positions

Comment: GNAT allows the discriminant’s position to be defined, but not the tag of a tagged record - [GNAT RM 6.24](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_rm/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/implementation_advice.html#rm-13-5-1-17-22-record-representation-clauses).

Comment: And, come to think, there would have to be a place for the tag/discriminant, which would have no equivalent in the C.

Comment: The OP said that they are "converting" a C program (into Ada, one assumes), not trying to link Ada with C. So the presence of a tag or discriminant should not be harmful, unless the whole record is being sent/received in some I/O. But even so, the I/O would need something similar to a tag or discriminant, to show what kind of record is being sent.

Comment: I think @NiklasHolsti may be right here! In fact, it’s not clear that OP couldn’t eliminate the pointers in the header and use Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists over `access List_Element’Class`.

Comment: Yes, this program has, as @NiklasHolsti says, no requirement here to interact with any C program. However, there is a requirement to be as close to the C program that is being translated as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this - especially if you are going to go with Address Overlays and/or Unchecked_Conversion

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   type Header_Record is
      record
         First_Item  : Integer;
         Second_Item : Boolean;
         Third_item  : Integer;
      end record
     with Convention => C;
       
   for Header_Record use
      record
         First_Item  at 0 range  0 .. 31;
         Second_Item at 0 range 32 .. 47;
         Third_Item  at 0 range 48 .. 79;
      end record;
   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   type Item_Record_1 is
      record
         Header    : Header_Record;
         DoNotCare : Float;
      end record
     with Convention => C;
   
   for Item_Record_1 use
      record
         Header    at 0 range  0 .. 79;
         DoNotCare at 0 range 80 .. 111;
      end record;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   type Item_Record2 is
      record
         Header : Header_Record;
         Rfc3092 : Boolean;
      end record
     with Convention => C;
   
   for Item_Record2 use
      record
         Header  at 0 range  0 .. 79;
         Rfc3092 at 0 range 80 .. 95;
      end record;
   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here, we are specifying the exact bit layout. It's a bit of pain that you'll need to use one level of indirection ie

```
Item_Record1.Header.First_Item
```

However, this should work. Also, always remember to use

```
Convention => C
```

Since Ada record layouts and C struct layouts may vary considerably - which is to be expected, given Ada's rich semantics.

EDIT: In response to portability issues. Although, the OP did not specify that it *must* be portable, it's still no problem ...

```
   with Interfaces.C;

   subtype int is Interfaces.C.int;

   type Header_Record is
      record
         First_Item  : Interfaces.C.int;
         Second_Item : Interfaces.C.int; --bool?
         Third_item  : Interfaces.C.int;
      end record
     with Convention => C;
       
   -- Exact values very likely to be different, for demo only
   for Header_Record use
      record
         First_Item  at 0 range  0 .. int'Size;
         Second_Item at 0 range  int'Size + 1 .. int'Size * 2;
         Third_Item  at 0 range  int'Size * 2 + 1 .. int'Size * 3;
      end record;
```

Comment: If the need were to share a stucture between Ada and C (which is not what the OP wants to do) I agree that a nested "header" record is a good approach. However, specifying the bit-wise layout makes the code unportable and is also very cumbersome. Usually it should suffice to use types from Interfaces.C for all the components and Convention => C for all record types. If that does not work, one would have to find out how the C compiler actually lays out the structure, and duplicate that by Ada representation specs -- ugh and likely very unportable.